# Python faster way to take logarithm of N-dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays

My question is trivial, nevertheless I need your help. It's not a problem to take a `np.log(x)` of an array. But in my case this array could be N-dimensional/Tensor (`N=2..1024` and 100 samples in each dimension).

For `N=4` calculation of element-wise `np.log(x)` takes **10 seconds**. I need to take this `log(x)` in a cost function for optimization, thus, all process of optimization takes roughly **2 hours**.

So, the question is how this `log(x)` can be implemented in faster way for N-dimensional arrays. Is it really possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please provide a [MCVE]

Comment: If NumPy performance becomes an issue, it may be time to switch to C++.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the array is N-dimensional or 1 dimensional. N-dimensional arrays are just views of 1 dimensional arrays in numpy (in the most complex case strided views). Intel-Numpy has an multithreaded, SIMD-vectorized version of np.log which is hard to beat. (giving about 4 GB/s throughput on float32 and float64, which is faster than a simple array copy in numpy  on a quad core)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe multiprocessing can help you on this situation

Answer (score 0):

The numpy `log` function is implemented in C and optimised for handling arrays, so although you may be able to scrape a bit of overhead off by writing your own custom log function in a lower-level language, this will still remain the bottleneck. If you want to see a big speed increase, you'll need to implement your algorithm differently.

Is it really necessary to take the log of all these elements? You mention that each dimension can have 100 samples, do you plan on averaging these samples? If so you can reduce the number of logarithms you need to compute by using the fact that log(a) + log(b) = log(ab), and so the average [log(a0) + log(a1) + ... + log(aN)]/(a0 + a1 + ... + aN) is the same as log(a0*a1*...*aN)/(a0 + a1 + ... + aN).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys,

the problem was a big amount of entries that I had to go through for processing. I just found another cost function for my optimization.

But, to speed up exactly this code - I think the idea with self made log table exactly for my type of signal can make it work.